¿como encuentro la llave que une a dos tablas?
Utilizando las tablas HumanResources.Employee y Person.Person, crea un query para obtener los nombres de los empleados (FirstName y LastName), así como el título de su puesto y fecha de nacimiento.
Nota: Para este ejercicio deberás identificar cual es la llave que une a estas dos tablas.
Estoy utilizando la base de datos de sql AdventureWorks2019 pero la tabla de HumanResourses le faltan los datos de (fisrtName y LastName) trate de modificarlo con alter table pero no me dejo mi pregunta es ¿como modifico o clono la base de datos de solo una columna ? y como identifico la llave que une a ambas tablas si con inner join no me ha dejado.

Comparte el código, lo que llevas o has intentado.
